# Trying to create an Express app at the command line

Tags: node.js, express

I have Ubuntu 13.10 and I installed Node.js using:

`sudo apt-get install nodejs`

I then installed Express using:

`sudo npm install -g express`

I had to use sudo for the express installation because I got errors when I tried to do it without.

The problem is when I try to create an express app or even type `express -v` at the command line nothing happens i.e.:

`kwal0203@Kanes-laptop:~$ express -v`

`kwal0203@Kanes-laptop:~$`

I can see the express files have been installed in the `usr/local/lib/node_modules/express` directory and the is also a file named `express` in the `usr/local/bin/` directory which I assume is some type of shortcut or link or something.

Any ideas on why express is not working?

Thanks any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was simply to install the nodejs-legacy package:

`sudo apt-get install nodejs-legacy`